# Why is leading whitespace in a q element treated differently from other inline elements?

Tags: html, css, browser, whitespace, removing-whitespace

It seems that leading whitespace inside a `<q>` element is always preserved (albeit normalized to a single space), while this isn't the case for most inline elements. For example, the following code ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbowp340/)):

```
<br> a <q>test</q> b <a href=#>test</a> c
<br> a <q>  test</q> b <a href=#>  test</a> c
<br> a <q>test  </q> b <a href=#>test  </a> c
<br> a <q>  test  </q> b <a href=#>  test  </a> c
```

Renders like this in all modern browsers I've tested (Chrome, FF, and Edge):

[image: inconsistent spacing around q element]

In the second and fourth line, the `<q>` is rendered with initial whitespace, while the `<a>` is not. Why is this?

**EDIT:** Adding the following CSS to the fiddle above:

```
a::before, a::after {
   content: '"';
}
```

Makes them render identically. So it seems to have something to do with the CSS `::before` selector.

Comment: Not really sure about this, but it could be because <q> tags are mostly used with block tags(the white space preservation is a property of the block tags).

Comment: This might help: https://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

Comment: @VivekaAgarwal I don't think that is the issue, since both `<a>` and `<q>` are classified as [phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2). The example also shows that, by default, `<q>` elements don't expand horizontally.

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML and everything to do with CSS. Whitespace rendering is handled entirely by CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Chrome's docs on default styles for HTML elements](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css#L82), the default style for the `<q>` element (quote) is:

```
q::before {
    content: open-quote;
}

q::after {
    content: close-quote;
}
```

As you noticed, if you apply the same style to the `<a>` element (anchor), you get the same results:

```css
body {
  font-size: 200%;
}

q {
  background-color: #AAF;
}

a {
  background-color: #FAA;
}
a::before {
  content: open-quote;
}

a::after {
  content: close-quote;
}
```

```html
<br> a <q>test</q> b <a href=#>test</a> c
<br> a <q>  test</q> b <a href=#>  test</a> c
<br> a <q>test  </q> b <a href=#>test  </a> c
<br> a <q>  test  </q> b <a href=#>  test  </a> c
```

The key to understand this lies on the explanation of what are `::before` and `::after`. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before), they create a pseudo-element that is the first (for `::before`) or last (for `::after`) child of the element matched. So you can imagine that an inline element with a quote inside was added as the first child of each `<q>`.

For example:

```
<br> a <span><span>"</span>    b</span>
```

Shows one space before `b`, while:

```
<br> a <span>    b</span>
```

Does not show the space before `b`.

You can see it in action here:

```css
body {
  font-size: 200%;
}

q {
  background-color: #AAF;
}

a, span {
  background-color: #FAA;
}
```

```html
<br> a <q>test</q> b <a href=#>test</a> c
<br> a <q>  test</q> b <a href=#>  test</a> c
<br> a <q>test  </q> b <a href=#>test  </a> c
<br> a <q>  test  </q> b <a href=#>  test  </a> c
<br> a <span><span>"</span>    a</span>
<br> a <span>    a</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of normal **white-space** css rule, which is applied by default here, is to collapse multiple whitespace to one space. When you add content with before and after it's not multiple whitespace anymore, hence it doesn't collapse.

Note that it doesn't have anything to do with leading or trailing spaces, or inline or not, or the `q` element. All whitespace behave this way except if you change the white-space rule.

You can see the result if you change your CSS to:

```
body {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zxvsehs6/

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly due to the fact that the < q > tag has been designed to do that specific function: quote a piece of text. If that piece of text has white space, that space would be displayed. The quote is meant to "copy" a piece of text, hence being a quote. All other tags don't have white space because they are the developer's input, so that developer controls where they want space to be shown. In a < q > tag on the other hand, the contents of the tag are displayed exactly as typed, to actually "quote" a section of text.

In the end, it's down to how the developers of HTML chose to create the tag. The above paragraph is simply reasoning of their choice.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate, since the `q` element does not preserve all whitespace. Newlines and multiple spaces are treated just as they are in a link. Could you point to the part in the HTML specification that creates this difference?

Comment: @Mangara In the end, simply using a <pre> tag does essentially the same thing, though with different intention. These tags were created with this purpose, but for different reasons. <pre> is used to preserve all whitspace, whilst <q> as you mentioned does not.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the white-space to be removed but what you can do is deduce the amount of white-space simply by adding a negative margin on the pseudo elements of the element you are trying to target.

Take for example this simple paragraph of text. I found the solution of adding a negative margin offset best worked for me:

html:

```
<p>This is my paragraph of text to demonstrate how this will work for you too!</p>
```

css:

```
<style>

p {

    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: verdana;
}

//Pseudo element for the opening quote
p::before {

    content: open-quote;
    margin-right: -5px;
}

//Pseudo element for the closing quote
 p::after {

    content: close-quote;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
</style>
```

Note:  The amount of margin you will require for the before and after pseudo elements is likely to vary, for example, you may find you need increase/decrease the margin on one side more than you do on the other as I found was the case for me, but this will work. Font-sizes and styles etc... will also add to the required negative margin you will need to set, bearing in mind this does not actually remove the white-space completely, but rather, just decreases it to a minimal ideal amount to suit your context. Have a play around with negative margin values I have added here to see how it works... it works and I know it is more of a hack than a proper solution... it just does not seem possible to remove the white-space added by default on block quote elements making it a bit of a tedious process to set the ideal negative margin to best suit any context.